# URL working in local but not in production

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I am developing website in magento. I tested it in local and it works fine.

Then i pushed my code into production but it's not working up in there.

It shows me "cms-index-noroute-". I wanted to debug So I deleted copy from my local and copied all the files using ftp from production. But still it works into my local but not working into production server.

Don't know what the problem.
Let me know if you can think of any reason why it's not working..

Any Help would appreciated.

Comment: Did you clear the cache? Did you rebuild your url rewrites index? If the dev environment is on windows and live environment is on linux them you might take a look at the file names. Windows file names are case insensitive and on linux are case sensitive.

Comment: Have you changed base_url in the "core_config_data" table ?

Comment: @Marius : i disabled cache. Even i tried to load page directly using siteurl/index.php/page, still the same problem. i am using mac and live environment is on linux.

Comment: @chinto : I don't understand what are you saying.

Comment: @BSThakrar. Most probably it's a case (in)sensitivity issue. Can you post the code you are using?

Comment: CMS pages are stored in database. Did you push the CMS page up to your production environment database?

Comment: Did you A) make sure all the file/folder ownership/permissions are properly set in the production environment B) change the base URLs in core_config_data to the new site's url, remembering the trailing slash (`http://www.example.com/`) C) clear the cache **after** doing **both** the preceeding. Also the way the question is asked, is this a whole website you're trying to move from dev to live?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you are getting 404 error. Did you got the 404 error on all page except the home page ..?If yes, please try to load your page like http://yoursiteurl.com/**index.php**/anypage.html  .Try to add index.php like above I mentioned. Now your page load correctly then, you need to modify your .htaccess file in your root directory. open your .htaccess file and search for the following **RewriteBase** . Modify your RewriteBase like this.
**RewriteBase /yoursitename/**    or **RewriteBase /**

Comment: No for now i designed only one page. I already tried it this way siteurl.com/index.php/page , but it didn't work. :(

Comment: i solved this problem when i created it from scratch.